# Lstlisting duplicate caption

Tags: listings, captions

I've been trying to insert the code to my LaTeX document. I used this piece of code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:rws}, captionpos={bottom}, caption={Pseudo-code of RWS Selection}]
r = Random(); /* Uniformly distributed random number in [0,1] */
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i < population.size; i++)
    sum += individual(i).probabilityOfSelection;
    if (sum >= r)
        select(i)
\end{lstlisting}
```

However I get duplicated caption at the top of the listing and also at the bottom. If I don't use `captionpos={bottom}` I get caption on top of the listing. Any idea what might be causing it?
Here's what I get:

[image: Duplicate description]

Thanks

Comment: Use `b` instead of `bottom`. This looks like a bug, apparently, **b**o**t**tom is interpreted both and leads to `top` and `bottom` caption

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks. I would have never thought that it would interpret bottom as **b**o**t**tom

Comment: very interesting bug ;) Do you want to report it @ChristianHupfer or shall I do it?

Comment: @StefanPinnow: Go ahead. You answered the question, now it's your job :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, done ;)

Comment: For the record: It package author will not fix this issue. The manual clearly states: "`captionpos=<subset of tb>` specifies the positions of the caption: top __and/or__ bottom of the listing."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just provide `captionpos={b}` - as it is stated in the manual - it is working fine.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    label={lst:rws},
    captionpos={b},
    caption={Pseudo-code of RWS Selection}
]
r = Random(); /* Uniformly distributed random number in [0,1] */
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i < population.size; i++)
    sum += individual(i).probabilityOfSelection;
    if (sum >= r)
        select(i)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

(Nonetheless it is the question, if the "non-valid" value shouldn't raise an error ...)

Comment: Oh dear, thank you. It's so weird that it doesn't notify you that "bottom" is invalid value